# When using MIN - Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the below query throwing an error that I can't quite understand why:

```
      Select * from Correspondences
      where case_id in(000021,00000991,000081,0000731)
      and case_id in(Select min(comm_date_utc) from Correspondences where case_id in               (000021,00000991,000081,0000731))
```

SQL server gives me this error:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Anyone able to help me understand why and what I should try to get around this one?

Comment: Why are you compairing a `caseid` -- which is clearly an integer or string like an integer -- to a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
  Select c.*
  from Correspondences c
  where case_id in(000021,00000991,000081,0000731)
  and comm_date_utc = (Select min(comm_date_utc)
                       from Correspondences c2
                       where c2.case_id = c.case_id
                      );
```

The problem with your query is that it compares a `caseid` to something like a datetime.  This query returns the first record for each case, based on the time.  The latter seems much more likely as the intention of the query.